# Creating a filled curved surface with TikZ

Tags: diagrams, tikz-3d

I'm trying to color the surface of a cylinder using an isometric perspective with TikZ. Is this something TikZ is capable of? What I've done is approximating the surface with two rectangles, which looks fine. The error is visible, though. I could always add more rectangles, of course.

But is there a shortcut way to do this, or is it not worth going through the effort of doing it "properly?"

Having a less tedious way of filling surfaces would be neat for projects in the future.

### Code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(-1cm,0.5cm)},x={(1cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}]
    %Behind Surface
    \draw[dashed] (2, 0, 0) -- (2, -1.5, 0);
    %Surface
    \fill[color = black!45!white, opacity = .4] (-2, -1.43, .451) -- (-2, -1.228, 0.86) -- (2, -1.228, 0.86) -- (2, -1.43, .451);
    \fill[color = black!45!white, opacity = .4] (-2, -1.43, .451) -- (-2, -1.5, 0) -- (2, -1.5, 0) -- (2, -1.43, .451);
    %Wedge
    \draw (-2,0,0) -- (-2,-1.5,0);
    \draw (-2, -1.5, 0) -- (2, -1.5, 0);
    \draw[canvas is yz plane at x = 2] (0:-1.5) arc (0:-35:-1.5);
    \draw (-2, 0, 0) -- (-2, -1.228, 0.86);
    \draw[canvas is yz plane at x = -2] (0:-1.5) arc (0:-35:-1.5);
    \draw (-2, -1.228, 0.86) -- (2, -1.228, 0.86);
    \draw (2,0,0) -- (2,-1.228,0.86);
    \draw (2,0,0) -- (-2,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The relevant package is `tikz`, along with the `3d` library.

### Result

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fill the same way as in 2d. I kept your coordinates (even though they are not fully isometrical, the `perspective` library has a predefined `isometric view`) but changed the roles of y and z to simplify the code. The reason for that is that arcs are automatically in the xy plane. In addition, it is useful to use cylindrical coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(1cm,-0.5cm)},z={(1cm,0.5cm)}, x={(0cm,1cm)},
    declare function={R=1.5;alpha=35;H=2;},
    radius=R,line join=round,line cap=round]
    % behind surface
    \draw[dashed] (0, 0,H) -- (0,R,H);
    % filled surface
    \draw[fill=black!45!white,fill opacity=0.4] 
     (0,R,-H) arc[start angle=90,end angle=90-alpha]
     -- (xyz cylindrical cs:radius=R,angle=90-alpha,z=H)
     arc[start angle=90-alpha,end angle=90] -- cycle;
    \draw (0,R,-H) -- (0,0,-H) -- (xyz cylindrical cs:radius=R,angle=90-alpha,z=-H); 
    \draw (0,0,-H) -- (0,0,H) -- (xyz cylindrical cs:radius=R,angle=90-alpha,z=H);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the drawing and filling are combined in one command. I also introduced "functions" for recurring parameters such as the opening angle `alpha`, radius `R` and half-height `H`.

The cylindrical coordinates are defined in the `3d` library and documented in section 40.1 of version 3.1.10 of the pgfmanual. You can also define your own cylindrical coordinates for a cylinder in x-direction and draw the wedge in the `isometric view` of the `perspective` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}
\makeatletter 
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{yzx cylindrical}
{%
  \pgfset{/tikz/cs/.cd,angle=0,radius=0,x=0,#1}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tikz@cs@y}{\tikz@cs@xradius*cos(\tikz@cs@angle)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\tikz@cs@z}{\tikz@cs@xradius*sin(\tikz@cs@angle)}%
  \pgfpointxyz{\tikz@cs@x}{\tikz@cs@y}{\tikz@cs@z}%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[isometric view,
    declare function={R=1.5;alpha=35;H=2;},
    radius=R,line join=round,line cap=round]
    % behind surface
    \draw[dashed] (yzx cylindrical cs:radius=0,x=H) coordinate (T) -- (yzx cylindrical cs:radius=R,angle=180,x=H) ;
    % filled surface
    \draw[fill=black!45!white,fill opacity=0.4,variable=\t,smooth] 
        plot[domain=180:180-alpha] (yzx cylindrical cs:radius=R,angle=\t,x=-H)
        -- plot[domain=180-alpha:180] (yzx cylindrical cs:radius=R,angle=\t,x=H) -- cycle;
    % remaining lines    
    \draw (yzx cylindrical cs:radius=R,angle=180,x=-H) -- (yzx cylindrical cs:radius=0,x=-H) coordinate (B) -- (yzx cylindrical cs:radius=R,angle=180-alpha,x=-H)
    (B) -- (T) -- (yzx cylindrical cs:radius=R,angle=180-alpha,x=H); 
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about command `xyz cylindrical`?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter These are cylindrical coordinates, which get defined in the `3d` library, which Simon Lederhilger loads because they are using `canvas is yz plane at x` in their code. These coordinates are described in section 40.1 "Coordinate Systems" of the pgf manual.